# ¿Por qué el envío de correo funciona en local y no en un servidor?

Tags: laravel, mail

Tengo un proyecto en laravel el cual funciona perfectamente en local, el envío se realiza y me llegan los correos, el problema es cuando lo subo al servidor, porque no se envían los correos, aquí esta el código:

.env

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=ac7b4116dc441d
MAIL_PASSWORD=e8cc705122ada9
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`
```

*mail.php*

```php
<?php
return [
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
 'from' => [

        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),

        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),

    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
 'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

*mailControler.php

```
public function contact(Request $request)
    {
        $subject = "Atención al Cliente Gamamateriales";
        $for = "correos.atenciongama@gmail.com";
        Mail::send('email', $request->all(), function ($msj) use ($subject, $for) {
            $msj->from("correos.atenciongama@gmail.com", "Cliente Gamamateriales");
            $msj->subject($subject);
            $msj->to($for);
        });
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé cual será el problema pero te comento que en mi .env tengo:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
```

Tal vez deberías consultarlo con la gente que te provee el servidor, si funciona en local el problema debe estar por ahí, saludos.

Comment: ya he intentado tambien con SSL, le he movido el monton de cosas y nomas no jala, me sale que no se puede conectar o que se agota el tiempo de espera

Comment: En mi proyecto esa configuración me la dió la administración del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor está bloqueado algo de la configuración para enviar con smtp. Prueba colocar:

`MAIL_MAILER=sendmail`

Me suele suceder en algunos servidores y con eso se soluciona.

Saludos!

Comment: lo he intentado y no me da error, pero no me manda el correo, se le mueve algo mas?, otra cosa, se sube algun archivo ademas del .env? soy algo nuevo en esto de laravel

Comment: Si no te da un error en pantalla, deberías revisar en `storage/logs/laravel.log` para ver si te muestra algún problema. Otro problema puede ser el puerto, probá con el 465. Pero creo q lo mejor que podés hacer es crear una cuenta de correo en tu servidor y probar con un correo y configuración real.